# How action and reducers are connected with each other in react redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am new to react and redux. I have gone through many online tutorials on react redux but still not able to understand how action and reducer is connected. If I am right, we import action in container/component, we import reducer in a file where we create a store. So there is a connection between container - action, and there is a connection between reducer and store but in action file we dont import reducer. So how action is connected to reducer. I know that we have a type of action which will be checked in switch case in reducer. But how does it get passed to reducer.

Answer (score 3):

*Very High Level Overview*

**Action** - Actions can update state

```
{ type: ACTION_TYPE, somePayload: payload }
```

The redux store exposes out a `dispatch` function, that ultimately wraps an action creator.

```
mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    someWrappedAction: () => dispatch(actionCreatorFn()),
    someOtherWrappedAction: val => dispatch(otherActionCreatorFn(val)),
  }
}
```

`useDispatch` Hook returns the `dispatch` and you wrap action yourself

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()

<button onClick={() => dispatch(someActionCreatorFn())}>
  Do Action
</button>
```

**Reducer**

The reducers form a state tree, starting with the root reducer passed to the redux store. The "connection" is made (conventionally) via the `mapDispatchToProps` and `connect` HOC. (*Now can get the `dispatch` from `useDispatch` hook*)

Reducers are **pure** functions that take two arguments, current state and an action, and returns the next state.

```
(currentState, action) => nextState
```

> *So how is each dispatch in mapDispatchToProps connected to the appropriate reducer...*

When you dispatch an action creator it passes the action object to the root reducer. The action object is passed through the entire state tree and any reducers that process the action `type` consume it.

Comment: I did not understand it fully. I dont have mapDispatchToProps function in container. I only have mapStateToProps.

Comment: @Nilesh Ok, in your question you asked how actions and reducers were related. `mapStateToProps` function is the first argument to `connect` and simply returns an object that maps redux state to props that are passed to your component.

Comment: Cleared my doubt regarding connecting action and reducer, thanks. We import what every action define and use in dispatch while passing payload etc

Comment: @DrewReese You're saying that if I ran an action every single reducer is going to get involved until it found the matching `type`?

Comment: @Melly Yes, sort of; when you dispatch an action to a redux store, each and every reducer function will act on it, either by specifically handling that action and returning *some* new state slice, or using the default case and returning the current state slice. Any reducer function can potentially handle any dispatched action.

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you for this explanation.  In your response, you described how "when you dispatch an action creator it passes the action object to the root reducer".  How is it passed?  In my current project, there is a reducers/ directory with an index.js file that combines and exports the reducers.  But this export is only called inside ReduxStore.js (which is not called anywhere).  Is this all done under the hood with react-redux when using useDispatch and useSelector?

Comment: @JeffersonPaulJones Basically you are calling `store.dispatch`. The store object handles passing the action object to the root reducer function. Yes, it's abstracted under-the-hood. You just fill in, or provide, the individual reducer functions that compute the next state.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: [dispatch](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/createStore.ts#L225) function takes `action` as an argument and calls `currentReducer(..., action)`.

---

When you call [creteStore(`reducer`)](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/createStore.ts#L343), the returned object contains `dispatch` and `subscribe` functions.

When you (or react-redux library) call `subscribe(listener)`, redux will remember your listener function (in case of React, the listener has to make sure the component re-renders with new props, context, state, or refs - depending on concrete implementation).

When dispatching an action with `dispatch(action)`, the dispatch function will call `reducer(action, state)`, modify redux internal currentState then call each `listener()`.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR; The store's internal mechanism identifies the reducer function that should handle the dispatched action based on the action's type.**

Here, I'll take a classic example of making a counter app.
We make an action creator that dispatches an action with a specific type:

```js
export const incrementCounter = () => {
  return {
    type: 'INCREMENT_COUNTER',
  };
};
```

Now, we make a reducer that takes state and action as arguments.

```js
const initialState = {
  counter: 0,
};

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT_COUNTER':
      return {
        ...state,
        counter: state.counter + 1,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

1. In your component, you call `dispatch(incrementCounter)`. This dispatches the action returned by the incrementCounter action creator.
2. The Redux store receives the dispatched action.
3. **The store's internal mechanism identifies the reducer function that should handle the dispatched action based on the action's type.**
4. **The store invokes the corresponding reducer function, passing the current state and the dispatched action as arguments.**
5. Inside the reducer, a switch statement (or other logic) is used to determine how to update the state based on the action's type.
6. The reducer returns a new state object or a modified version of the current state.
7. The Redux store updates its internal state with the new state returned by the reducer.
8. If the state has changed, React Redux (or other connected components) triggers re-rendering of the subscribed components that rely on the state.